# cell.textLabel setText with more than one item

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using [cell.textLabel setText: title]; which is working great, but i would like to add a few more in the **same cell**.

For example:

```
[cell.textLabel setText: title];
[cell.textLabel setText: venue];
[cell.textLabel setText: offer];

[cell.textLabel setText: title];
[cell.textLabel setText: venue];
[cell.textLabel setText: offer];

[cell.textLabel setText: title];
[cell.textLabel setText: venue];
[cell.textLabel setText: offer];

etc etc
```

But of course, this just overwrites the previous. So i just get the 'offer' in each cell.

How is something like this done? Please keep in mind, this is my very first app, one step up from 'hello world', so forgive me if this this seems a stupid question :)

thanks,

Comment: you can create custom cell and add more UILabel to that cell.. Read this. http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: custom cells are good for this but since this is your first app if you want something simple why not just append title, venue offer and make it all one label? Another consideration with either method is do you have the room? if you dont have enough horizontal room then a custom cell is probably what you want and you can size it to have your labels go vertical as needed

Comment: See the [Customizing Cells](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18) section of the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451)

Comment: The idea of mushing strings together seems wrong to me... will lead to styling issues and other problems down the line. So i went with the custom cell link posted here. Worked a treat! The lesson was clear, but a little hard to implement as the referencing wouldn't take. But after some playing around i got it to work. Thanks for the help!!

@Bhumeshwerkatre , if you add this link as a form of answer, id be happy to tick it off as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the info @Bhumeshwer katre ... Teach a man to fish. :)

I recommend anyone who stumbles on this question to follow this link, very easy to do and you will learn lots, if your a beginner like myself: http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Answer (score 1):

You can combine strings like this:

```
NSString *celltext;

celltext = title;

celltext = [celltext stringByAppendingString:@" "];
celltext = [celltext stringByAppendingString:venue];
celltext = [celltext stringByAppendingString:@" "];
celltext = [celltext stringByAppendingString:offer];
[cell.textLabel setText: celltext];
```

Alternative solution:

```
NSString *celltext;
celltext = [celltext stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", title, venue, offer];
[cell.textLabel setText: celltext];
```

Comment: A rather inefficient approach, how about a mutable string?

Comment: NSMutable string is not needed here. The best is this: celltext = `[celltext stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", title, venue, offer];` but he mentioned that he is a beginner so I chose the easiest to understand solution.

Comment: @NikosM. Don't teach beginners bad habits. There is nothing hard to understand about `stringWithFormat:`. It's a much better solution than your current answer. Teach a new dev the right solutions. Use `stringWithFormat:` or `NSMutableString`.

Comment: i wonder how much over head there really is here in a practical run time environment. I've dealt with slowness issues in apps and i'm not sure this unless there are tons of labels would create one.

Comment: with that said i'm open to learning what the load difference is here if anyone had some sort of hard numbers.

Comment: This will lead to styling issues i feel. But nice to know it can be done.